# Relation between the dimension of vector spaces and dimension of the space

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, random-matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory

Let $A \in \mathrm{GL}(d, \mathbb{R})$ be an irreducible matrix. Assume that $\{V_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a non-zero proper subspace $\mathbb{R}^d$ with dimension $t<d,$ such that $AV_{n}=V_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Suppose that $m$ be a minimum number such that there is $m$ such that $A^m V_0$ and $V_{m}$ are at the same subspace (there might be several $m$ such that  $A^m V_0$ and $V_{m}$ are at the same subspace) . Is there any relation among $m, t,$ and $d?$ for instance, is it true that $t.m=d?$

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but could you not take $d=2,t=1$ and $A$ a rotation matrix? Then you could pretty much get whatever $m$ you want.

Comment: @JimConant : You are right. I meant $m$ is the minimum number.

Comment: I think that @JimConant's [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417037/relation-between-the-dimension-of-vector-spaces-and-dimension-of-the-space#comment1070229_417037) was that, without any other condition, you could, for $d = 2$, $t = 1$, and any $m$ you please, choose a collection of subspaces that realises that $m$ (including $m = \infty$ and $m = d/t = 2$).  Thus, with no further information on the subspaces, it seems not possible to give any information about $m$.